# Return two separate queries in a stored procedure with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in MySQL that will query a table based on the employee's department number. If the department number is present in the table, it should return only those employees belonging to that department. On the other hand, if it's not present in the table, then I want to return all records from the table.

However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Table Schema:

| empNo | empName | salary | deptNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| number | name | salary | dept number |

My stored procedure so far:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmpData(
        IN deptNum INT
)
BEGIN
    IF deptNum THEN
        SELECT * FROM empdemo
        WHERE deptNo = deptNum;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM empdemo;
    END IF;
END //
```

I used the if else because I didn't know of any other way to break this query down. If anyone has any other suggestions please post them!

Comment: Apologies, I meant if it is present in the table

Comment: Then you want to use IF EXISTS  https://www.delftstack.com/howto/mysql/mysql-if-exists/

Comment: No, this isn't what I'm trying to do. Read my question again, I want to return all records if the condition is not true. But I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need in this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM empdemo
WHERE empdemo.deptNo = deptNum
   OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM empdemo
                   WHERE empdemo.deptNo = deptNum )
```